# rationale behind the evaluation in tensorflow's tutorial code cifar10_eval.py

Tags: tensorflow

In TF's official tutorial code 'cifar10', there is an evaluation snippet:

```
def evaluate():    
with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
            # Get images and labels for CIFAR-10.
            eval_data = FLAGS.eval_data == 'test'
            images, labels = cifar10.inputs(eval_data=eval_data)

            # Build a Graph that computes the logits predictions from the
            # inference model.
            logits = cifar10.inference(images)

            # Calculate predictions.
            top_k_op = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, labels, 1)

            # Restore the moving average version of the learned variables for eval.
            variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(
                cifar10.MOVING_AVERAGE_DECAY)
            variables_to_restore = variable_averages.variables_to_restore()
            saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)

            # Build the summary operation based on the TF collection of Summaries.
            summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

            summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.eval_dir, g)

            while True:
                eval_once(saver, summary_writer, top_k_op, summary_op)
                if FLAGS.run_once:
                    break
                time.sleep(FLAGS.eval_interval_secs)
```

At runtime, it evaluates one batch of test samples and prints out 'precision' in the console every other `eval_interval_secs`, my questions are:

1. each time `eval_once()` is executed, one batch of samples (128) are dequeued from the data queue, but why I didn't see the evaluation stop after enough batches, 10000/128 + 1 = 79 batches? I thought it should stop after 79 batches.
2. Are batches from the first 79 sampling mutually exclusive? I'd assume so but want to double-check this.
3. If each batch is indeed dequeued from the data queue, what are the samples after 79 times of sampling? some random sampling from the entire duplicate data queue again?
4. since `in_top_k()` is taking in some unnormalized logit values and output a string of booleans, this masks the internal conversions of softmax() + thresholding. Is there a TF op for such explicit computations? Ideally, it'd be useful to be able to tune the threshold and see different classification results.

Please help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can see the following line in "inputs" def of cifar10_input.py

   ```
   filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
   ```

   More about  tf.train.string_input_producer :

   ```
   string_input_producer(
       string_tensor,
       num_epochs=None,
       shuffle=True,
       seed=None,
       capacity=32,
       shared_name=None,
       name=None,
       cancel_op=None
    )
   ```

   num_epochs : produces each string from string_tensor num_epochs times before generating an OutOfRange error. If not specified, string_input_producer can cycle through the strings in string_tensor an unlimited number of times.

   In our case, num_epochs is not specified. That's why it does not stop after few batches. It can run unlimited times.
2. By default, shuffle option is set to True in tf.train.string_input_producer.  So, it shuffles the data first and copies that shuffled 10K filenames again and again.

   Therefore, it's mutually exclusive. You can print filenames to see this.
3. As explained in 1, they are repeated samples. (not any random data)
4. You could avoid using tf.nn.in_top_k. Use tf.nn.softmax and tf.greater_equal to obtain boolean tensor that has softmax value above the specific threshold.

I hope this helps. Please comment if there is any misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Much clearer now. So in order to evaluate the whole test set, we can specify 'num_epochs' to say, 79. About Q2, did you mean to say 'all batches are NOT mutually exclusive', i.e., each batch is sampled with replacement?

Comment: num_epochs = 1 means input_producer reads all file names once. Each batch is different from other (considering num_epochs=1) as far as my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks! I'll verify using num_epochs=1

Comment: hm.. I got a runtime error when specifying 'num_epochs=1' in string_input_producer(): tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs. Any ideas why? Using TF v1.0

Comment: yeah...you have to run this.  " init_local = tf.local_variables_initializer(); sess.run(init_local) ". num_epochs is a local variable.

Comment: @galactica, can you accept the answer if your queries are cleared. Thanks

Comment: thanks! one more thing, after initializing that variable and specifying num_epochs=1, it's weird this line of code never got executed: "precision = true_count / total_sample_count". in other words, no precision is printed. do you know why?

Comment: @galactica Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144012/discussion-between-hars-and-galactica).